# View Pager circle Indicator with different Layouts

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, viewpagerindicator

I want to make view pager circle indicator for my app. View Pager is working perfectly with circle indicator two but i am unable to add different layouts in it i.e. right now it is just changing textview values when user swips the screen. Please tell me how to implement layouts so that i can view different layouts when swip
Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ViewPager viewPager;
private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
private ArrayList<Integer> listOfItems;

private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
private int dotsCount;
private TextView[] dots;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initViews();
    setViewPagerItemsWithAdapter();
    setUiPageViewController();
}

private void setUiPageViewController() {
    dotsLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewPagerCountDots);
    dotsCount = myViewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new TextView[dotsCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
        dots[i] = new TextView(this);
        dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
        dots[i].setTextSize(30);
        dots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
        dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);            
    }

    dots[0].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
}

private void setViewPagerItemsWithAdapter() {
    myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(listOfItems);
    viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);
}

//  page change listener
OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < dotsCount; i++) {
            dots[i].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
        }
        dots[position].setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

    }
};

private void initViews() {

    getActionBar().hide();

    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    listOfItems = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    listOfItems.add(1);
    listOfItems.add(2);
    listOfItems.add(3);
    listOfItems.add(4);
    listOfItems.add(5);
}

//  adapter
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private ArrayList<Integer> items;

    public MyViewPagerAdapter(ArrayList<Integer> listOfItems) {
        this.items = listOfItems;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_pager_item, container,false);

        TextView tView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.PageNumber);

        tView.setText(listOfItems.get(position).toString());

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
        return view == ((View)obj);
    }


    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        View view = (View)object;
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView(view);
    }
}
```

Please Help!

Comment: Your question is unclear. What doesn't work exactly? What have you tried. It is generally better to put less code and only the parts that are relevant. Good questions are usually short or have a summary of some sort.

Comment: in this method initViews(), you see that listOfItems.add basically changing text values to 1,2,3,4 and 5 but i want to show different layouts when user swip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in `instantiateItem()`.  Just inflate and fill out the view you want for that page.

```
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view;
        switch (position) {
        case 0: // page 1
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container,false);
            // TODO set up your page 1 views
            break;
        case 1: // page 2
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container,false);
            // TODO set up your page 2 views
            break;
        case 2: // page 3
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.page3, container,false);
            // TODO set up your page 3 views
            break;
        // etc. etc. etc.
        }

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(view);

        return view;
    }
```